# Possible to install AR Drone SDK 3.8 on Windows 8.1?

Tags: ar.drone

Is it possible to install the AR Drone 3.8 SDK on Windows 8.1? Has anyone found the zip/source for the 3.8 SDK? It's not publically available as far as I can see from searching the forums, google and the parrot website. The 2.0 SDK is downloadable as a zip [here](http://forum.developer.parrot.com/t/welcome-to-parrot-for-developers-forum/8).

According to [this](http://developer.parrot.com/blog/2016/ARSDK-3-8-release/) you need to use Android/Google's Repo to download the SDK but AFAIK repo wont work on Windows?

Note I am aware of the existence of the .NET Ar Drone SDK but I will be developing in C/C++ not C#.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to install the Parrot ar. Drone SDK on windows 8.1?